# URL parameters with DXA

Tags: dxa, custom-url

I started playing around with Tridion and DXA just recently, and I'm having problems to understand how custom routes work.

I have a Component Template which has its own DXA view, view model, controller, and action. I've created the correspondent objects in Tridion and the classic examples work properly.

I need to be able to configure custom routes to the action in order to receive parameters in the URL (eg. `/books/{genre}/{year}`) but I couldn't find how. Can you help me there?

Reading some other questions here I found some people suggesting to do the routing in `Global.asax`. This works, but the result is the rendering of the Component Template view only. I need to be able to route the whole page, being able to read the URL parameters.

Looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After struggling a bit with the matter, I found an alternative way of handling this. I'm not sure it's the best solution, though.

1) Add the custom route with the URL parameters to the `Global.asax` redirecting to the page controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "BooksCustomRoute",
           "books/{genre}/{year}",
           new { controller = "Page", action = "Page", pageUrl = "books/index" },
           new { pageId = @"^(.*)?$" }
        ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Core");
```

2) Once your component template action gets called, you will be able to retrieve the parameters from the route data:

```
public ActionResult Entity(CustomViewModel entity)
{
    string genre = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["genre"]?.ToString();
    string year = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["year"]?.ToString();

    return View(entity.MvcData.ViewName, entity);
}
```

This way I was able to pass and retrieve URL parameters loading the whole page instead of the single action/view.

If anyone has a better idea, please let me know.

Comment: It's better to override the `EnrichModel` method instead of the `Entity` method.

Comment: If you really want your URL parameters in the URL path, then this seems like a valid approach.  You could also use URL query parameters, in which case you don't need a separate route (again, see `ListController` as an example).

Answer (score 3):

DXA uses a rather unusual, composite Model and View rendering flow: a *Page Model* contains *Region Models* which in turn contain *Entity Models*.

Most incoming HTTP requests are handled by a *Page Controller* (see `Global.asax.cs`: the Page Controller handles all URLs which are not explicitly routed to some other controller). The Page Controller retrieves the (composite) Page Model and selects a *Page View*.

Normally, the Page View doesn't render the entire Page Model itself, though: it delegates rendering of the Regions to *Region Views* using the `@Html.DxaRegion` or `@Html.DxaRegions` helper methods. Technically speaking, a combination of a *Region Controller* and *Region View* is used to render a Region Model.

The Region View, in turn, normally delegates rendering of the *Entity Models* to *Entity Views* (using `@Html.DxaEntity` or `@Html.DxaEntities`) . Again, a combination of *Entity Controller* and *Entity View* is used to render an Entity Model.

For Entity Models, it is possible to configure a custom Entity Controller in CM (in the CT metadata). Such a custom Entity Controller should inherit from `EntityController` and should override the `EnrichModel` method.  This method will be invoked just before the Entity Model gets rendered and is intended to enrich the Entity Model, typically based on URL parameters.

See, for example: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Controllers/ListController.cs

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your answer but I had already tried customizing the URL for the Entity view/action/controller. The problem then is that the custom URL return was only the partial view, and my need was to route to the whole page.