# How to add an id as anchor/fragment to resolved link in DXA

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa2.2, link-resolver

We are using DXA 2.2.3 and have the following mappings:

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
[SemanticEntity(EntityName = "Link", Prefix = "l")]
public class Link : EntityModel
{
    [Include]
    [SemanticProperty("l:internalLink")]
    [SemanticProperty("l:externalLink")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The Url property is resolved to:

`/content-management/sdl-tridion/sdl-tridion-sites/`

But I would like to add an Id of a Component which it is linked to as an url fragment/hash, so for example I would like to have an url

`/content-management/sdl-tridion/sdl-tridion-sites/#93730`

In addition, this fragment should appear in the resolved link only in case the linked Component is based or not based on a certain Schema. So I need to check the Schema Id and then consider adding an anchor to a link.

What is a proper way to handle such a case? Any solution on web app side?

Comment: please refer to this link - https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/url-parameters-with-dxa if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you map a Component Link field to a property of type `string`, the semantic mapping will use the resolved link URL which is injected in the DXA R2 Data Model by the DXA Model Service/Extension.

Unfortunately, this part of link resolving is not customizable. However, if you map a Component Link field to an Entity Model, you will have access to the underlying Component ID (it will be mapped to the Entity Model's `Id` property).

If you give that Entity Model a `string` property which is annotated with `[SemanticProperty("_self")]`, you will also have access to the resolved link URL.

You can then construct the combined URL yourself (for example, by adding a property to your Entity Model which combines the two).

Comment: BTW: You can also map the Component Link to a property of type `Link`. That also provides both the resolved URL and the Component ID.